# Why didn't Spider-Man gain natural spinnerets with his initial powers?

Tags: spider-man, powers, marvel

I know he had them for a time pre-Civil War, but why wasn't organic web spinning one of the powers Peter Parker got when he was initially bitten by the radioactive spider? His strength, agility and wall-crawling are all abilities that spiders have. I would argue that above all, a spider is known for spinning webs and Parker should have developed that natural ability as well, instead of having to invent his own webbing fluid.

With all his other powers, was natural webbing too much for a single hero in the 60's?

**UPDATE**

In recent Amazing Spider-man comics, Peter meets a girl named Cindy that was bitten by the same radioactive spider he was and she has natural web spinning powers (Amazing Spider-Man Vol 3 #4). How can that be?

Comment: yeah but... if they were being literal, and he got more powers that resembled a spider's directly... wouldn't the webs come out of his mouth? Not really a fanciful power if you ask me.

Comment: Well, actually most spiders spin it from the uh . . . opposite end of their body.

Comment: Sorry but I voted to close because the question is kind of about proving a negative.  Why didn't spider-man grow eight legs?  etc.

Comment: @Mark Rogers He did.  http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-6wQT4Smti18/T7HbaxgDw7I/AAAAAAAAACA/n-j9QceCtVM/s1600/What-If2V042.jpg

Comment: Listen bud, he's got radioactive blood.

Comment: @MarkRogers: I guess, but the question seems to be asking for an out-of-universe answer, i.e. why did Spider-Man’s creators not have him develop natural web shooters? And that could (in theory) be answered, because creators get interviewed about their creations.

Comment: @Jamil: [And his dick falls off](http://devour.com/video/scientifically-accurate-spider-man/).

Comment: @will - lol i probably should have used a less likely example.  Fair enough, I wont vote to close again.

Comment: @Jamil Or alternatively to PaulD.Waite's video, spiders do have something that comes out the wrist-like area, but [it's not webbing](http://membracid.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/the-horrible-truth-about-spidermans-anatomy/)

Comment: “In recent Amazing Spider-man comics, Peter meets a girl named Cindy that was bitten by the same radioactive spider he was and she has natural web spinning powers (Amazing Spider-Man Vol 3 #4). How can that be?” — That sounds like a separate question. Feel free to ask it as such.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I asked the writer Dan Slott directly on Twitter and basic gist of his answer was that different people can have different reactions to being bit by the same spider. He also mentioned that Peter still has the potential to make natural webs in him and it's possible he'll show them later on.

Comment: @Jamil: nice nice. If you fancy it, feel free to ask it as a question here anyway, *and* answer that question yourself, referencing Slott’s reply on Twitter. That’s all fair game.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven’t been able to find any discussion by Stan Lee describing the deliberations over what Spider-Man’s exact powers should be.

Specifically on “was natural webbing too much for a single hero in the 60's?”, looking at the original comics it seems more likely that it wouldn’t have been *enough*.

Academic intelligence and scientific aptitude is sometimes as important to Spider-Man as his physical abilities, especially in the early comics. (He works out how to insulate himself against Electro’s abilities in Amazing Spider-Man #9, for example.)

Inventing his own web-shooters is a way to illustrate the extent of his intelligence. Spider-Man’s a nerd — if he’s nerd enough to invent his own webbing, that’s a cool thing.

Self-made web shooters also provide useful limitations to the power. Stan Lee *has* discussed how [he intended Spider-Man to be a super-hero with everyday teenager problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYMSKIHYSTg) – money worries, girl trouble, etc. Being responsible for making his own web shooters means they could write stories where he ran out of fluid, or his shooters stopped working, giving it the more practical, realistic tone they were going for.

Comment: There’s some good discussion of Spider-Man’s webs in the answers to this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21252/how-much-web-can-spider-man-produce

Comment: I guess it makes sense when it comes to audience appeal.

Comment: ...and when he ran out of fluid is when he reached for his glock 19.

Answer (score 1):

Spider Man 2099 did get natural spinnerets, which may support your theory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099#Powers_and_abilities

Comment: Yeah, he's the reason I began to ask the question about Parker.