# What happens to Spider-Man's webs?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

A favorite view of Spider-Man (at least in movies and games) is of the hero web-slinging his way through the streets of New York City. But what becomes of all the web ropes that Spider-Man discards as he moves from building to building? We don't see them hanging around the city, so presumably someone removes them.

Do people collect them as souvenirs? Does Spider-Man come back later to clean up after himself? Does the city employ a group of cleaners just to remove the webs?

Comment: Are you talking about comics, movies (which series?), or some other media? The answer and the evidence may be different depending on which you want?

Comment: In the original comics, his webs dissolve after an hour or two, which is why [he never made any money from them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85198/440).

Comment: @Thunderforge Any or all is fine. The question came to me after watching a trailer for the newest Spiderman game.

Comment: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/26flgj/marvel_what_happens_to_spidermans_web_after_each/), [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-to-Spider-Mans-webs-after-he-shoots-them-out), [screenrant](https://screenrant.com/spider-man-web-trivia/) although it is unclear what source of canon you’re looking for and therefore your range of answers could be quite broad.

Comment: If it helps to narrow the scope, then specifically to the movie series staring Toby Maguire, as that's the canon I'm most familiar with.

Comment: @Edlothiad Is there any canon source where it *doesn't* dissolve after a certain amount of time?  I feel like this is the answer across all canons.

Comment: This question seems to lack research effort.

Comment: In the comics and 90's cartoon, Peter says he deliberately designed the webbing to break down after an hour.

Comment: The real question is what happens to Spider-Web’s men.

Answer (score 10):

The general idea, although the exact answer varies by Universe, is that the webs dissolve after a few hours.

Comment: This answer seems to lack research effort

Comment: I was going for an answer which gives over the general idea because the exact answer varies greatly from universe to universe

Comment: Perhaps you might improve it by offering some examples from a range of universes.

Answer (score 10):

## In the MCU,

Peter Parker's web formula dissolves after two hours (or so).

> **Spider-Man:** (to Aaron Davis)  Hey, that's gonna dissolve in **two hours.**
> **Davis:** No no no no… come fix this.
> **Spider-Man:** Two hours—you deserve that!
> ...
> <sub><sup>*Spider-Man: Homecoming*</sup></sub>

## In other universes,

I don't have any specific examples, but I'm not aware of any evidence that suggests any different behavior.

Comment: As good as this answer is, I cannot forgive that you have left out the "I've got ice-cream in here"

Answer (score 2):

In the most recent movie, *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, there is a scene where he is interrogating the low-level criminal played by Donald Glover after sticking his hand to the car with webbing.

When Spider-Man leaves he tells him that it will dissolve in about 2 hours.