# Are there any stories where a Spider-Man with organic webbing runs out of webbing?

Tags: spider-man, marvel

In a few parallel universes of Spider-Man, Peter Parker is given the power of **organic webbing** in addition to his other powers. I want to know whether any comic book story (or TV show, videogame etc) includes a scenario where his webbing supply empties for a while and he has to wait for his silk glands to refill.

This doesn't have to be limited to Spider-Man 2099 or Noir, I just don't know of any other version of Spider-Man (excluding Sam Raimi's films) where he has organic webshooters.

Print-screens/copies of comic panels are greatly welcome!

Comment: Related: [How much web can Spider-man produce?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21252/23159)

Comment: It is likely that any Spider-Man video game in which Spidey can run out of webshooters depicts Spider-Man 2099 and Spider-Man Noir running out of webshooters as well, as they just act as skins and the character keeps its mechanics. (Not that I know of any).

Comment: @Catma - If you pick up [SPIDER-MAN 2099 VOL. 1](http://marvel.com/comics/collection/24112/spider-man_2099_vol_1_trade_paperback) or [SPIDER-MAN 2099 VOL. 2](http://marvel.com/comics/collection/47743/spider-man_2099_vol_2_tpb_trade_paperback) likely you'll find many instances where Miguel O’Hara runs out of webbing as it was a rather regular occurrence early on in the original, and very entertaining, [Peter David](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_David) run.

Comment: Are we including Ultimate Spiderman?

Comment: According to The Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A-Z published in 2009 "Parker could produce silk from glands within his forearms, limited by his health and nutrition."

Comment: i recall sam raimis spiderman movie *inspiring* the change from web shooters as a gadget to peter naturally prpducing his own webbing

Comment: *Spider-Man: Shootin’ Cobwebs*, brought to you by Sony Pictures and Marvel Studios, summer 2031.

Answer (score 7):

While fighting Iron Man in Amazing Spider-Man #544, Peter unloaded all the webbing he had stored in his body at the time in order to hold Iron Man prisoner.

Iron Man [broke free a few pages later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvXbl.jpg) when his repulsors came back online (they were temporarily offline as a result of [having overheated earlier in the fight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkmN6.jpg)).

[image: Peter uses all his webbing on Iron Man] [image: Iron Man cocooned in the webs]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I hesitate to offer this as an Answer, but I find the scene provides a strong implication Peter is quite aware of "running out of ammo" with organic webs.  He knows how to "fill the tank" in the fastest way.

"Amazing Spider-Man" #668 (2011).  In the middle of the "Spider Island" story, Peter advises Carlie Cooper on her newfound abilities.
[image]