# Has Spider-Man ever run out of webs?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

In the comics, Spider-Man shoots out webs from web shooters (unlike the first three movies). As they are actual devices, they must have a finite amount of webs stored in them.

Therefore, **Have Spider-Man’s web shooters ever run out of webs in the comics?**

(By this I mean during a fight or while swinging around the city).

This is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21252) question. That asks how much web can he *produce*? I want to know whether during a fight he tries to shoot a web and finds out that his web shooter has run out of webs.

---

P.S. If you still feel it’s a duplicate then put it as a comment and wait for a day while I see what I can do about it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much web can Spider-Man produce?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21252/how-much-web-can-spider-man-produce)

Comment: Dupe of [Are there any stories where a Spider-Man with organic webbing runs out of webbing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68075/are-there-any-stories-where-a-spider-man-with-organic-webbing-runs-out-of-webbin)

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e5/36/65/e53665cc889bce051669015d21e4d066--spider-man-sarcasm.jpg

Comment: https://rnmiz43724.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/18802i93E4A8F60AF07214?v=1.0

Comment: @Valorum: Since I found one example where I could trace it to a specific comic, I posted it. I also added the images you provided, with attribution.

Comment: I read Spider-Man comics growing up and it happened frequently enough to make me wonder if he had enough web fluid in his web shooters. I can't think of specific examples, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it happened in the [March 1963 issue](https://thegothamrogue.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/the-time-capsule-spider-man-march-1963-menace-to-society/), "Menace to Society".

[image: Three panels of a Spider-Man comic. One, the Chameleon, disguised as a police-man, is about to pull a fuse as Spider-Man realizes Chameleon's disguise. Two, the lights are out, but Spider-Man can still sense Chameleon. Three, Spider-Man realizes he's out of the fluid that makes his webbing.]

Valorum also provided two images of other times it has happened.

**[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1. #190](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_190)**:
[image: In the middle of a crisis, Spider-Man runs out of web-fluid and cries, "Nuts!"]

**[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1. #230](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_230)**:
 [image: Spider-Man checks the cartridges at his waist and realizes he used up his entire supply to web up "Juggy" that morning.]